# Timeout during install

Tags: nouveau, drm

I'm trying to install Ubuntu for the first time using a USB stick.

But i keep getting this timeout

```
Nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: base-2: timeout
```

Any ideas? It stops right there, even when I try to do a disk check.

Comment: Boot with `nomodeset`.